# Programatically clear a single DNS cache entry in Windows and Linux in C++

Tags: c++, dns, gethostbyname

I am wondering if there is a way to programmatically clear a single DNS cache entry in both Windows and Linux. Or if there is some other way to force a gethostbyname call to not use the local cache.

Clearing the entire cache would not be ideal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely recall making the request to the cache with the AUTHORITATIVE bit set.

You can't do that with gethostbyname(): you have to call the resolver on UDP port 53.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified my original question. I would prefer not to send the request directly, as I would like the application to hit the normal resolution order, ie if it's an entry in the hosts file, I would like the hosts file used etc.